# What is the best way to split a column of data in a txt file based on the first delimiter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash, csv, text

I have a large number of txt files with a single column of data. There are no headers in the files.

The data are an email address followed by a `:` and then a string of varchar, which sometimes includes `:`s.

My goal is to convert the following

```html
abc@example.com:v@rch:r$tR:ng
def@example.com::multipleTypes
xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:
```

To a tsv with headers.

```html
column1           column2
abc@example.com   v@rch:r$tR:ng
def@example.com   :multipleTypes
xyz@example.com   &ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:
```

These files will then be uploaded into a postgres database.

Any insight/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `awk '{sub(/:/,"\t")}1' file`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can do that. Without `/g`, its substitution replaces the first occurrence on each line:

```
sed -e 's/:/\t/' *.txt > file.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can split the text at the appropriate position and export the hole with `COPY` to an TSV

this would look like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytab(mytext text)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytab VALUES('abc@example.com:v@rch:r$tR:ng'),('def@example.com::multipleTypes'),('xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 'column1', 'column2'
> UNION ALL
> SELECT  substr(mytext,1, strpos(mytext, ':') -1) col1,
> substr(mytext,strpos(mytext, ':')+1) col2 FROM mytab
> ```
>
> ```
> ?column?        | ?column?         
> :-------------- | :----------------
> column1         | column2          
> abc@example.com | v@rch:r$tR:ng    
> def@example.com | :multipleTypes   
> xyz@example.com | &ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:
> ```

> ```
> COPY (SELECT 'column1', 'column2'
> UNION ALL
> SELECT  substr(mytext,1, strpos(mytext, ':') -1) col1,
> substr(mytext,strpos(mytext, ':')+1) col2 FROM mytab) TO '/tmp/ind.tsv'  CSV  HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  substr('def@example.com::multipleTypes',1, strpos('def@example.com::multipleTypes', ':') -1) col1,
> substr('def@example.com::multipleTypes',strpos('def@example.com::multipleTypes', ':')+1) col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1            | col2          
> :-------------- | :-------------
> def@example.com | :multipleTypes
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  substr('xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:',1, strpos('xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:', ':') -1) col1,
> substr('xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:',strpos('xyz@example.com:&ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:', ':')+1) col2
> ```
>
> ```
> col1            | col2             
> :-------------- | :----------------
> xyz@example.com | &ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cf2a69fa5959c0ff01ea40d7f219db60)*

Answer (score 0):

@choroba is correct with Sed. This can also be done in python.

```
x = 'def@example.com::multipleTypes'

x = x.split(':', 1)

print(x)
```

This splits the text at the first `:`

Answer (score 0):

Using bash parameter expansion for splitting the lines and printf to format the output:

```
printf "%-24s%s\n" "column1" "column2" ; while read -r line ; do printf "%-24s%s\n" "${line%%:*}" "${line#*:}" ; done <your_data.txt

column1                 column2
abc@example.com         v@rch:r$tR:ng
def@example.com         :multipleTypes
xyz@example.com         &ofTxtGoAfT3rThe:
```